# D3 connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I am very new to d3 and sql.. I want to connect my d3 visualisation to a simple database. So far I have loaded a simple csv file to d3 and this information is displayed by a simple scatterplot. I have the same information with the same fields in a table in a database and now I want to connect d3 to this database and display the same scatterplot (I want to do this as I will have a much more information to display in the future). I have written a php script to use to connect d3 to the database but I am unsure of what code to include in d3 to reach this file. This is my attempt in the d3 code snippet to reach php file:

```
d3.json("connection.php", function(error, data){
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.YEAR = parseYEAR(d.YEAR);
d.Number = +d.Number;
});
```

(year is on the x-axis and number is y).

Comment: It looks like you're going to want the output of your database script to be JSON. So you'll need `json_encode($dataFromQueryInAssociativeArray);` at some point. What is the current output of your script?

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined' @Iwnnay

Comment: What is your current output when you go to "http:// yoursite/connection.php"?

Comment: I fixed it! thank you for your help, I didnt realise how to see my current output but now i was able to fix it! thanks for your help! @Iwnnay